# Detect sound levels from multiple running apps in android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to create an app in android that allows the user to look at all applications running and adjust the sound level of each application individually, similar to the volume mixer on Windows computers. However, after much research, I haven't found another app that does the same concept or any snippets of code that would help me with this. Does Android even support this capability with non-rooted phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android does not support different volume levels for different applications

Comment: Well I have noticed that when running multiple applications with sound, the sound is automatically equalized. So I was thinking of maybe of accessing the system sound and finding a way in that way? Or am I just being optimistic?

Comment: Due to fast-route audio in Android, I doubt there is any equalization but you can check sources of Audio Flinger.